# "Neither user 10046 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" but it's in my manifest

Tags: java, android

I added the permission of `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in the Manifest.xml and code is below.

```
TelephonyManager tm  = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
int cellID = location.getCid();
int lac = location.getLac();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cellID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, it crashed with the error message below.  Please check how to solve this kind of problem.

```
05-15 23:23:09.844 22602-22602/use.uevision.com.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: use.uevision.com.myapplication, PID: 22602
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication/cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getCellLocation: Neither user 10046 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getCellLocation: Neither user 10046 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.strong text
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
      at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getCellLocation(ITelephony.java:3311)
      at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getCellLocation(TelephonyManager.java:963)
      at cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
05-15 23:23:13.804 22602-22602/cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22602 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo should use [RuntimePermissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Startins with Android M you need to ask permissions at Runtime. Please refer to link.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
 }else{
           //do your job
 }
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication, PID: 10696
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication/cctvkim.truevision.com.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x261e60e

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.  I did as you told however I have got the another error message as above.  If I toast just "hello", it works but if I try to toast cellID or lac, it is crashed.  Any Idea??

Comment: another error message means another problem. If I resolved your problem - accept my answer. The another error message u've got looks like your location is still null and you trying to get a data from it. Surround it with if(location!=null)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add READ_PHONE_STATE permission to use TelephonyManager.
add this permission in your menifest file.